# UITabBarController remove controller from tab more

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have 6 tabs, I need remove some controller from tab "More"
[image]

When I select some controller on tab "More" and `NSLog navigationConroller.viewControllers`, `UINavigationController` have empty `UIViewController`

```
NSMutableArray *controllers = (NSMutableArray *) delegate.tabBarController.viewControllers;
    for (UINavigationController *item in controllers) {

        NSLog(@"show %@",item.viewControllers);
    }
```

[image]

and if I remove tab from `UIViewController` which I choice on tab "More", I have black screen

[image]

Comment: can you elaborate your question.What you want exactly,because at present it is not very clear

Comment: If you want to remove it in run-time then why have you added it in the first place? If you want 6 tabs and the tab-bar can display only 5 then you will have 2 rows in more tab's view controller. Just remove this 6-th tab from the XIB or in code (if you create your tabs in the code).

Comment: I need remove tab in some event, and when I remove tab, I have black screen